# Handling Nested Forms in HTML/php

Tags: php, html

I try to figure out how to handle two nested forms. The first one sends data from select-option dropdown to `another_file.php`. The nested one should send data from check boxes to current file and should be handled by `isset($_POST['...'])`. Here is my simplified code:

```
    if (isset($_POST['a'])) 
        {
         // do something
        }

          if (isset($_POST['b'])) 
        {
         // do something else
        }

        echo "<form action='another_file.php' method='post'>"; // begin of first form
            echo "<table class ='table table-hover table-condensed table-striped table-bordered'>";
            echo "<thead>";
            echo "<th>ID</th><th>Jídlo</th><th>Množství</th><th>por_cislo</th><th>Odebrat</th>";
            echo "</thead>";
            while($rows = $stmt->fetch()){

                echo "<tr><td>" . $rows['id'] . "</td><td>".$rows['jidlo'];
                echo "<select name =".$rows['id']."_".$rows['por_cislo']."> ";
                $stmt2 = $db->query($q2);
                echo "<option value ='nic'> (vyberte potravinu) </option>";
                $max_por_cislo = $rows['por_cislo'];
                while($rows2 = $stmt2->fetch())
                {
                    echo '<option value="'.$rows2['id'].'">'.$rows2['jidlo'].'</option>'; 
                };
                echo "</select>";
                    echo "</td> <td>" . $rows['mnozstvi'] . "g <input name = '".$rows['por_cislo']."' type='text' value = '-'></td><td>".$rows['por_cislo']."</td>";
echo "<td><form action ='this_file.php' method = 'post'>"; // begin of nested form
        echo "<input type='checkbox' id='atur_peg' name='idecko[]' value=".$rows['id']."*".$rows['por_cislo']." /></td></tr> ";

            };
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='pc' value=".$plan_cislo.">";
            echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><input name = 'go' type='submit' value='OK'/></td><td colspan='2'><input type = 'submit' name ='a' value='ADD'/></td>";
          echo "<td><input type = 'submit' name ='b' value='DELETE checked'/></form></td></tr>"; // end of nested form

            echo "</table>";
        echo "</form>"; // end of first form

Is
```

there any way to do this correctly?

Comment: You have a few errors in your code I think... because at `while($rows = $stmt->fetch())` you're assigning it to $stmt->fetch and in that case the while loop would never terminate. And I'm not really getting the question being asked here, could you  please elaborate?

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper You are wrong. This thing works correctly. Obviously that's not the problem I am trying to figure out...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nested forms, use jquery to detect checkbox being checked and then change the form action url. Something on this line.. You will have to modify the same to suit your needs.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#formname").on("change", "input:checkbox", function(){
    if( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
      $('#formName').attr('action', 'this_file.php');
      $("#formname").submit();
    }

});
```

});